# Common Lisp: Attach x recursively to list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to add, say, x to every element of a list.
For example:

```
(queue 3 '(1 2 3))
```

would give

```
((3 1) (3 2) (3 3))
```

The code below apparently does not do what I want. 
Any hints please?

```
(defun queue(x y)
 (cond
  ((null y) nil)
  (t (cons x (queue x (rest y))))))
```

Comment: probably you want  ((3 1) (3 2) (3 3)). Note the added parentheses indicating a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're prepending x to to the result of applying queue to the rest of y, without using y's first element at all. So basically you're throwing away all values of y and replacing them with x.

You want to do `(cons (list x (first y)) (queue x (rest y))))))` instead.

You could of course just use map to do this, but I assume this is an exercise in recursion.

Comment: Perfect! And the explanation was pretty descriptive. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You've got the answer for the recursive version already.

Here is the usual Lisp way using MAPCAR:

```
(defun queue (item list)
   (mapcar (lambda (list-element)
              (list item list-element))
           list))
```